# Simple Firmware Interface Library

Tags: library

[The Simple Firmware Interface (SFI)](https://simplefirmware.org/) is a replacement to the [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI)](http://www.acpi.info/).  I was wondering if there is an OS independent library for SFI similar to what the [ACPI Component Architecture (ACPICA)](https://www.acpica.org/) is for ACPI; basically something that abstracts away the nuances of the specification.  I know SFI is much simpler than ACPI but it would be nice not to have to reinvent the wheel if possible.

Note: On the [SFI download page](https://simplefirmware.org/downloads) there are some git links that no longer work and a statement that the OS independent files in the Linux SFI implementation would be made available on that page, which they are not.  I guess one could always rip out said files from Linux but I would like to use a library with a thought out interface if possible.